# How to just highlight the Max and the lowest cost value in the Tableau table dashboard column

Tags: tableau-api, visualization, tableau-desktop

How to just highlight the Max and the lowest cost value in the Tableau table dashboard column. I don't want the whole column to get highlighted, just the max and the min value in red and green color?
Can anyone please help!
[image]

My dashboard has a table and one of the column is eCPM, just in this column CPM, I want the $4.41 to highlighted as Green and $7.50 to be in red.

The solution provided works well! But it also applied to my Grand Total, which I don't want. Also I want just eCPM and Market column to be highlighted, because other columns doesn't fit the min/max criteria.

Any help??

[image]

Comment: Separate Legends could be used for Coloring specific measures, however, in this case since we added the Color Calculation to Colors, it might not work. I wish I could help on this, hope someone else could answer. Applying Min/Max to the entire table can be done by using 'Compute Using--> Table(down) selection. Also, use 'Total Using--> Hide Option to deselect the Grand Total.

Comment: Yes, I used Compute Using--> Table(down) but doesn't make any difference. Also, can't deselect the Grand total since I want that to be there. Anyways, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a calculated field by using the window_max and window_min functions:
IF SUM([columnname]) = WINDOW_MAX(SUM([columnname])) THEN "Max"
ELSEIF SUM([columnname]) = WINDOW_MIN(SUM([columnname])) THEN "Min"
ELSE "Neither"
END

Add the calculated field to Color

Manually try to grey out the color of the Neither colors, like so:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was about to answer!

Comment: @Anu thank you! This solves the purpose. How do I get the row background to be highlighted, instead of just the text?

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @Nicolaesse Could you please help me further on this??

Comment: Sorry but I don't this that you can apply conditional formatting to only certain columns, unfortunately. Sad but true...